# Highcharts tooltip shadow angle

Tags: highcharts

I'm creating a theme for Highcharts and need to be able to configure the shadow angle on the tooltips. In some configuration areas, shadow allows for an object (ex: [plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.shadows](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.shadow)) but it seems that the [shadow setting on tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shadow) does not allow this. Is there a workaround or a global setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put css-style on your tooltip, in that way you can setup your shadow like that :

- First deactivate the default shadow :

  ```
  tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C',
      shadow:false,
      useHTML:true,
      formatter: function() {
          return '<div class="tooltip">Test</div>';
      }
      // Replace "Test" with the formatter you want, there are good examples
      // on their website.
  }
  ```
- And set the style of your tooltip :

  ```
  div.tooltip {
      -moz-box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #888;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #888;
      box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #888;
  }
  ```

Here is an live example : http://jsfiddle.net/PKFSs/

With that you can do whatever you want on your tooltip.

**EDIT :**
If you can't use css :

```
formatter: function() {
    return '<div class="tooltip" style="-webkit-box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #888;box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #888;">Test</div>';
}
```

I know it is not the best way, I'm trying to find a better solution, but this one works.

Comment: `formatter` is a good call. I need to be able to package the whole theme into one .js file, though so I can't include the CSS. This is an infrastructure project, and asking all the departments to include 5 lines of css in a separate file isn't an option. I'll see what I can do with the `formatter` option, though.

Comment: It seems there is no easy choice to do that... I think my solution will be the best in term of time to implement/simplicity....